# How to sort an java.util.ArrayList<ParentType> based on ChildType?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, enums, type-erasure

```java
public interface Human<T> extends Comparable<T>{ }

public class Men implements Human<Men>{
  public Men(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
.....
}

public class Women implements Human<Women>{
 public Women(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
.....
}

public class MainTest{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      List<Human> engineers= new ArrayList<Human>();
        engineers.add(new Men("A")); 
            engineers.add(new Women("A"));
        engineers.add(new Men("C"));
        engineers.add(new Men("E"));
        engineers.add(new Men("Z"));
            engineers.add(new Women("J"));
        engineers.add(new Women("B"));
        engineers.add(new Men("X"));
        engineers.add(new Men("O"));
        engineers.add(new Women("G"));   

       Collections.sort(engineers);

       System.out.println(.... print the engineers array...)
}
```

> Output
>
> Men(A); Men(C); Men(E); Men(O); Men(X); Men(Z) Women(A); Women(B);
>   Women(G); Women(AJ);

My sorted the arraylist should to be `initially sorted in terms of the TYPE (Men or Women) and the secondary sort is based on firstname`. How can I best possibly accomplish this?

I tried the `Collections.sort(....)`

Couldnt get the desired results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean

```
public interface Human extends Comparable<Human> {}
```

That is: Human is comparable to other Humans. That being the case, if you want to compare Humans based on type followed by name, then your interface Human needs to express both of those properties:

```
public interface Human extends Comparable<Human> {
    enum Type { MAN, WOMAN }
    Type getType();
    String getName();
}
```

Then write an appropriate implementation of `compareTo()` to take both type and name into account, and use `Collections.sort()` to sort.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and `Collections.sort(List l, Comparator c)`

```
static final Comparator<Human> MyComparator =
                                 new Comparator<Human>() 
{
    public int compare(Human e1, Human e2) 
    {
            // Your custom comparison code goes here
    }
};

Collections.sort(engineers, MyComparator);
```

Additional info can be found via the tutorial on object ordering:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you guys are recommending this ?

```
public class HumanComparator implements java.util.Comparator<HumanBeings> {

    @Override
    public int compare(HumanBeings o1, HumanBeings o2) {
        if(o1 instanceof Men && o2 instanceof Men)
            return 0;
        else if(o1 instanceof Men && o2 instanceof Women)
            return -1;
        else if (o1 instanceof Women && o2 instanceof Men)
            return 1;

        return 0;

    }
}
```

> ....  and add more code to further sort by firstname...

Comment: More or less, except you shouldn't be using instanceof in this situation. Your `Human` should express its "type", as I described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592231/how-to-sort-an-java-util-arraylistparenttype-based-on-childtype/7592251#7592251).

Answer (score 1):

Comparator implementation `based on Ryan Stewart's solution`. Works great!

```
Collections.sort(engineers, new Comparator<Human>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Human o1, Human o2) {
        if(o1.getType().equals(o2.getType())) {
            return o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName());
        } else {
            return o1.getType().compareTo(o2.getType());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class HumanComparator implements Comparator<Human>{

@Override
public int compare(Human humanObj1, Human humanObj2) {
    int index;
    if(humanObj1 instanceof Men && humanObj2 instanceof Men){
        String firstName1 = humanObj1.getFirstName();
        String firstName2 = humanObj2.getFirstName();
        index = firstName1.compareTo(firstName2);
    }else if(humanObj1 instanceof Women && humanObj2 instanceof Women){
        String firstName1 = humanObj1.getFirstName();
        String firstName2 = humanObj2.getFirstName();
        index = firstName1.compareTo(firstName2);
    }else if(humanObj1 instanceof Men && humanObj2 instanceof Women){
        index =-1;
    }else if(humanObj1 instanceof Women && humanObj2 instanceof Men){
        index =+1;
    }else{
        index =0;
    }
    return index;
}
```

}

and you can sort the collection using  below :

```
  Collections.sort(engineers ,new HumanComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use "Comparator" interface.
Write a different class which implements this interface.
Then in compare method write the appropriate code which checks for the instance and then the member of the instance.